# The parameter isn't defined however, I defined it

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The parameter isn't defined however, I defined it.
I saved my data onto firebase and also in the PostData object class however, when I try to fetch it, it tells me that the parameter isn't defined.

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    PostData data;
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    final _uid = user.uid;
    print('Fetch method is called');
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('post')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot productsSnapshot) {
      _products = [];
      productsSnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        // print('element.get(productBrand), ${element.get('productBrand')}');
        _products.insert(
          0,

          PostData(

          0,

        [],
            Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,

        name,
        token,
        image,
        [],
            title: element.get('productTitle'),
            id: element.get('productId'),
            description: element.get('productDescription'),
            price: double.parse(
              element.get('price'),
            ),
            imageUrl: element.get('productImage'),
            productCategoryName: element.get('productCategory'),
            brand: element.get('productBrand'),
        true,

              // 0,
              //
              // [],
              // Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
              //
              // name,
              // token,
              // image,
              // [],
              // "",
              // "",
              // "",
              // 0,
              // "",
              // "",
              // "",
              // true,
        ),);
      });
    });
  }
```

Here is where I stored it, in PostData however, whenever I try to call it, it tells me that the parameter isn't defined. I am pretty sure I defined it so I don't know what to do or how to fix this issue.

```
 PostData(

      int likesCount,
      List likes,
      int timestamp,

      String postersName,
      String postersId,
      String postersImageUrl,
      List postSavedByUsers,
      String title,
      String id,
      String description,
      double price,
      String imageUrl,
      String productCategoryName,
      String brand,
      )
  {

    this.likesCount = likesCount;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;

    this.postersName = postersName;
    this.postersId = postersId;
    this.postersImageUrl = postersImageUrl;
    this.postSavedByUsers = postSavedByUsers;
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.productCategoryName = productCategoryName;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.isPopular = isPopular;
  }
```

here is the error i'm getting.

[image: error image]

Comment: why u not given datatype to title field?

Comment: Hi, what is a data type title.

Comment: `title` data type missing

Comment: can you include full model class

Comment: did you declare your variables in the model class?

Comment: @Peter Haddad hi, PostData is the class I stored all my firebase data in. I think it is my model class, it’s the only class I use to fetch my products.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you defined positional required parameters and not named parameters but you're trying to pass the name of the parameters (`title`, `id`, `description`, `price`, `imageUrl, productCategoryName, brand).

**Solution:**

Pass the arguments as positional required parameters (without the parameter names) like below:

```dart
  PostData(
    0,
    [],
    Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    name,
    token,
    image,
    [],
    element.get('productTitle'),
    element.get('productId'),
    element.get('productDescription'),
    double.parse(
      element.get('price'),
    ),
    element.get('productImage'),
    element.get('productCategory'),
    element.get('productBrand'),
 )
```